# Toggle custom fields?

Tags: customization, custom-field

I got a custom field and I want to toggle a specific custom field. So for example I have 2 custom fields named: Subject and Score. When viewing a single post the custom field 'Score' data is hidden until a user clicks on the button to see the data. How can I do this toggle effect?

Comment: Placing an if statement around the custom field score in the front end and check for the state of the checkbox like `if($statecheck == 1)`; `$statecheck`representing if the according checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: I'm not a programmer so I don't understand about the if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with jquery.

I have a similar code on use which you could probably easily edit to your needs:

load the admin js (I load css too but you can remove that)

```
function wpse181868_admin_css_js() {
    wp_register_style( 'bones_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/css/admin.css', false );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bones_admin_css' );

    //adding scripts file in the footer
    wp_enqueue_script( 'admin_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/js/admin.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse181868_admin_css_js' );
```

and then in the js check and show stuff as needed (I show different boxes for different post formats)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function checkFormat() {
        $('#attachments-gallery_attachments').hide();
        $('#featured_video').hide();
        if($('input[name=post_format]:checked', '#formatdiv').val() == "gallery") { $('#attachments-gallery_attachments').show(); }
        if($('input[name=post_format]:checked', '#formatdiv').val() == "video") { $('#featured_video').show(); }
    }

    $('#formatdiv input[type="radio"]').live('click', checkFormat);
    checkFormat();
});
```

---

**EDIT:**
In you theme's functions.php add this code

```
function wpse181868_admin_js() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var $input = $('<input type="button" id="s_s" value="Show score" />');
        $('input[name^="meta["]').each(function(){
            var val = $(this).val();
            if(val == "score") {
                var valueTD = $(this).parent().siblings();
                $(valueTD.find('textarea')).hide();
                $input.appendTo($(valueTD));
                $('#s_s').click(function(){ $(valueTD.find('textarea')).show(); $input.remove(); });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
<?php }
add_action('admin_footer', 'wpse181868_admin_js');
```

Comment: I just didn't understand what you just said since I'm not a programmer. Where do I put this code? what parts need editing?

Comment: So how did you come up having these two custom fields then? What are their IDs and you are able to modify the theme files right?

Comment: I created these fields with just using the gui in the create post area section. The two custom fields are named 'Subject' and 'Score'. Yes I can modify themes files

Comment: I'm sorry, with "create post area section" do you mean the "custom fields" section where you can add custom fields to the current post?

edit: and sorry, I really need some sleep right now, I'll give it a look in the morning.

Comment: yea that's what I mean.

Comment: Ok, check the edit and try it out. edit: Second, need to revise the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you still have this issue, but recently I have the same struggle...

And this is what I found.

Toggle with CSS only. I try showing you in the most simple way You could do this with JQuery, though.

HTML(single.php or page.php, or something)---------------------

```
<?php if ( $post->Scores ): ?>
  <div class="menu">
    <label for="A">Scores</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="A" class="B" />
    <div class="C">
      <?php echo nl2br( $post->Scores ); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

CSS--------------------

```
label {
    color: #3f3f3f;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

input[type="checkbox"].B{
    display: none;
}

.menu .C {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}

input[type="checkbox"].B + .C{
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

input[type="checkbox"].B:checked + .C{
    height: 200px;
}
```

---

Please customize CSS such as the height, margin, padding, color, etc as you like.

Hope this helps you and works for your site.